# Magento2 cannot remove item from wishlist

Tags: magento2, product, items

I'm trying to remove an item from the wishlist programmatically. My code snippet as following:

```
/**
     * @param integer $customerId
     * @param integer $productId
     * @return boolean
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function removeProductFromWishlist($customerId, $productId) {
        try {
            $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $product = null;
        }

        try {
            $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $customer = null;
        }

        $wishlist = $this->_wishlistFactory->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true);
        $ids = $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory->create()->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId)->load()->getAllIds();
        try {
            foreach ($ids as $itemId) {
                $item = $this->_itemModel->load($itemId);
                if ($item->getProductId() == $productId) {
                    $item->delete();
                    $wishlist->save();
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But it's doesn't work, when I calling this method from `Postman`, I'm getting an error:

```
{
    "messages": {
        "error": [
            {
                "code": 500,
                "message": "Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on boolean in /home/logbasex/IdeaProjects/clique-omnyfy/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Observer/Customer/RemoveWishlistItem.php:52\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/logbasex/IdeaProjects/clique-omnyfy/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Dotdigitalgroup\\Email\\Observer\\Customer\\RemoveWishlistItem->execute(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer))\n#1 /home/logbasex/IdeaProjects/clique-omnyfy/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Dotdigitalgroup\\Email\\Observer\\Customer\\RemoveWishlistItem), Object(Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer))\n#2 /home/logbasex/IdeaProjects/clique-omnyfy/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer))\n#3 /home/logbasex/IdeaProjects/clique-omnyfy/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magen' in '/home/logbasex/IdeaProjects/clique-omnyfy/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Observer/Customer/RemoveWishlistItem.php' on line 52",
                "trace": "Trace is not available."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any solution? Thank you!

Comment: I guess it could be a bug in dotmailler itself, if you dont need dotmailler can you try to desactivate it and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code to remove the wishlist item.

```
// $this->wishlist = \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist
$wish = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId);
$items = $wish->getItemCollection();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->getProductId() == $productId) {
        $item->delete();
        $wish->save();
    }
}
```

Let me know if you still facing any issues.

Thanks!

Comment: I already tried :) But getItemCollection() return empty collection. As same as: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316478/getitemcollection-returns-null-always-magento-2-3

Comment: So, the first check do you have any items on your wishlist?

Comment: Absolutely, I have two items in `wishlist_item` table. In my code snippet, I can get the item's productId but I can't delete item.